# Transforming $n\times k$ matrix of rank $k$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$ be a matrix with $n$ rows and $k$ columns. Suppose that the rank of $B$ is $k$. My question is does there exist an invertible matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $AB=[I_{k,k}\,\,\, 0_{n-k,k}]^T$, where $I_{k,k}$ is the $k\times k$ identity matrix and $0_{n-k,k}$ is a matrix of all $0$'s?

I would like to know how to proceed with a proof to this. The matrices $B$ and $[I_{k,k}\,\,\, 0_{n-k,k}]^T$ both have the same rank, so one can transform $B$ into $[I_{k,k}\,\,\, 0_{n-k,k}]^T$ by performing row and column operations, but that would also require multiplication on the right by appropriate elementary matrices, opposed to just multiplying $B$ on the left by some $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrices of size $n\times k$ represent linear transformations $\Bbb R^k\to\Bbb R^n$.

Let $b_1,\dots,b_k$ be the columns of $B$, and $e_1,\dots,e_k\in\Bbb R^k$ the standard basis vectors. Then the map represented by $B$  is the linear extension of $e_i\mapsto b_i$.

The rank of $B$ being $k$ means that $b_1,\dots,b_k$ are linearly independent. So, we can extend it to a basis $b_1,\dots,b_k,\ b_{k+1},\dots,b_n\ $ in $\Bbb R^n$.

Now define the map $\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$ for $A$ as (the linear extension of) $\ b_i\mapsto e_i$. 
It is invertible, and it satisfies the matrix requirement for $AB$ which translates to $ABe_i=e_i$ for $i\le k$.

Comment: Thanks very much! Extremely clear.